# Nested sections in UITableView and Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I've seen some tutorials how to make a UITalbeview with nested sections, but all of them are using predefined structure to hold the table data.

so:

Section
 SubSesction
   Item
   Item
 SubSection
   Item
 Subsection 
   Item
   Item
   Item
Section
  Subsection
   Item
....
and so on.

Now I'm trying to the the same, but taking the Items from core data, let's  Item entity has dateAdded and timeAdded, so the section will be according to dateAdded and subsections to be timeAdded.

What I've getting is to make the Section part with group by in core data, but how I can get the SubSection info?

```
    let countJulianDateAdded = NSExpressionDescription()
    countJulianDateAdded.name = "countItemsAtDate"
    countJulianDateAdded.expression = NSExpression(format: "count:(julianDateAdded)")
    countJulianDateAdded.expressionResultType = .Integer32AttributeType

    let sortDateDesc = NSSortDescriptor(key: "julianDateAdded", ascending: false)

    let fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")
    fetch.sortDescriptors = [sortDateDesc]
    fetch.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
    fetch.propertiesToFetch = [countJulianDateAdded,"julianDateAdded"]
    fetch.propertiesToGroupBy = ["julianDateAdded"]
```

so I will have count of groupings by date (count of sections) as fetch result.count and Dictionary which contains count of Items per Date per section(so num of rows per section) and the grouped dateAdded(so I use it for section header)

But I'm stuck now, how to make the same for the SubSections. I know not to think in SQL, but I have in my mind something like:

```
Select Count(dateAdded),dateAdded
       (select count(timeAdded),timeAdded
        from Item i2
        where i2.dateAdded = i1.dateAdded
        Group by timeAdded)
 from Item i1
Group By dateAdded
```

Any thoughts ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `timeAdded` as both a property to fetch, and a property to group by, like this:

```
let countJulianDateAdded = NSExpressionDescription()
countJulianDateAdded.name = "countItemsAtDate"
countJulianDateAdded.expression = NSExpression(format: "count:(julianDateAdded)")
countJulianDateAdded.expressionResultType = .Integer32AttributeType

let sortDateDesc = NSSortDescriptor(key: "julianDateAdded", ascending: false)

let fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")
fetch.sortDescriptors = [sortDateDesc]
fetch.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
fetch.propertiesToFetch = [countJulianDateAdded,"julianDateAdded","timeAdded"]
fetch.propertiesToGroupBy = ["julianDateAdded","timeAdded"]
```

you will get the count of items for each unique combination of `julianDateAdded` and `timeAdded`.  So I think this will provide the number if items for each subsection of each section.